# Changing numbers font features while changing shape

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, libertine

I am writing a document with the main font set up with old numbers, but I would like to have the "normal" style in the tables. This works but one particular table has some of the numbers in italic and somehow I cannot find a way of changing the font feature for these.

It turns out that the table is irrelevant and using `\itshape` or `\em` or `\textit{}` in normal text give the same result:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2px,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont [Numbers = {Proportional,OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

2189 89283 98239 8098 2983 098023 \textit{1392843902984u29830} {\itshape 1981987092183749280}

{
\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}, ItalicFeatures={Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}}}
2189 89283 98239 8098 2983 098023 \textit{1392843902984u29830} \itshape 1981987092183749280
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or have I hit a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With XeLaTeX I get the warning

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=Lining,Monospaced' (+tnum) not available for font
* 'Linux Libertine O/BI' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
```

that's probably the cause for this. I get the expected result by defining a new font family, instead of adding features on the fly:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=2pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont [Numbers = {Proportional,OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\libertinelf}{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

2189 89283 98239 8098 2983 098023 \textit{1392843902984u29830} {\itshape 1981987092183749280}

{\libertinelf
2189 89283 98239 8098 2983 098023 \textit{1392843902984u29830} \itshape 1981987092183749280
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @egreg, I am not getting any such messages with `LuaLaTeX`, and `XeLaTeX` for me does not work (can't find the font, but that is a completely different issue). Your solution works though.

Answer (score 5):

Fontspec has some issues with `lnum` and `tnum` when already using Oldstyle numbers.
One of the easiest ways to resolve this is by using the latest `libertine` package:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

2189 89283 98239 8098 2983 098023 \textit{1392843902984u29830} {\itshape 1981987092183749280}

\liningnums{%
    \addfontfeature{Numbers = Monospaced}
    2189 89283 98239 8098 2983 098023 \textit{1392843902984u29830} \itshape 1981987092183749280
}
\end{document}
```

[image: numbers]

Monospaced numbers also work (except for italic numbers):

[image: monospaced]

Answer (score 1):

Use libertine.sty:

```
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
 2189 89283 98239 8098 2983 098023 \textit{\libertineLF 1392 84390 29842 9830}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For this to be a usable answer you need to make this in to a complete working document (e.g. there is no document class and `\libertineLF` is not defined in the set-up I tried) and perhaps tell us which tex engine is to be used.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: `\libertineLF` is defined in the latest version of the `libertine` package (in fact `\liningnums` —which my answer uses— is defined as `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\liningnums}{\libertineLF}`). You might want to update.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: If you have a recent libertine package installed, \libertineLF will work with any of the LaTeX engines.

Comment: @Silex I confess, it has gone at least 3 days since I updated my distribution on this machine.  Adding `\documentclass{article}` is now sufficient to make the above code run.