# How to *disable* Lua's Microtype for a given tabular column?

Tags: tables, luatex, tabularx, microtype

I'm looking for a way to disable Lua's Microtype (note the capital M - [to distinguish from](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82001/microtype-settings-for-dummies) the lower case `microtype` *package*) in the first `tabular` column of the MWE given below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}
\setmainfont[Microtype, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures=TeX]{Verdana}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{l|}*{1}{X}@{}}

aaaaaaaaaaaa & \textbf{bbbbbbbbbb} \\
&\emph{ccccccccccccccc}\\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

<sub>This MWE isn't "optimized" to show the effect(s) of M/microtype, and thus perhaps ought to be improved accordingly...</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}
\setmainfont[Microtype, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures=TeX]{Verdana}
\newfontface\NoMicrotype[Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures=TeX]{Verdana}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\NoMicrotype}l | X @{}}

aaaaaaaaaaaa & \textbf{bbbbbbbbbb} \\
             & \emph{ccccccccccccccc} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

for the first l-column it already has no effect. you can see it in the X column with more text when there are linebreaks.

Comment: `LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.` ?

Comment: I cannot see such a message with lualatex from currrent TL2013

Comment: hmm, I'm still on TL2012... you think that's the bottleneck?

Comment: maybe. However, Verdana has no font features for Numbers.

Comment: That could also be a reason... in my "real-world" example, it is a column of numbers (e.g. 08/2010 – 11/2010). Does that mean that `\newfontface\NoMicrotype[...` would not work / be ineffective for such a column in this scenario?

Comment: my comment had nothing to with microtype. That will work. It was a comment for the fontfeatures. Are you sure, that your version of Verdana has proportinal numbers?

Comment: No, the font I'm using has *monospaced numbers*. Turning off `Microtype` for the whole document gave me the desired look for the numbers column... I'm confused. Is there a corresponding solution which will (also) work with *monospaced numbers* ?

Comment: I absolutely do not understand what you really want to have.

Comment: Truth be told, I'm figuring it out myself still ;) But you prodded me into the right direction, am reading up on [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85556/changing-numbers-font-features-while-changing-shape) and also the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty You're talking about monospaced numbers, but in your example you have only `Proportional`; maybe you could be clearer about your aim.

Comment: sure, it also works for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even though I believe – judging from your comments – that the microtypographical features have nothing to do with your actual problem (whatever this may be ...), let me just add for completeness' sake that the simplest solution to disable protrusion and expansion is to say:

```
\pdfprotrudechars=0
\pdfadjustspacing=0
```

They can be enabled again by setting both values to `2`, or by enclosing the text in a group.

Note, however, that you cannot use this methods to change settings within one paragraph; those settings that are in effect at the end of the paragraph will apply to the whole paragraph. In order to temporarily disable the features for only part of a paragraph, you can resort to Herbert's solution. (This is a general remark for future readers and not directed towards your problem.)

Comment: Extending on your v helpful remarks, this is what (also) works for me in my text (as you indicate) *within* a given paragraph: `\NoMicrotype{some text}`, as defined by `Herbert` in his answer.